# Create chart for fivestar note

Tags: 7, entities, rating, charts

I'm using Drupal 7, and [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar).

I try to display notes in the format of a pie chart.

If the note (= rating) is 5,2 on 10, I would like to have a circle of this type :

[image]

I tried [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) (with Google Charts as its charting engine) and [Google chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools), but I do not manage to obtain what I wish (using the Views integration).

With Google chart tools, I have [this problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118884/how-to-create-a-pie-chart-using-views-google-chart-tools) (only one value is shown), and with Chart nothing displays (i do not use aggregation, just fivestar field in views).

Would you know a solution?

A tabular of the data which I wish to display :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1 - Use Charts to create a pie chart

The sample image in your question doesn't look like a pie chart to me, instead it rather looks like a ***Gauge*** chart. If you want to try to create a pie chart anyway, using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, then have a look at [this feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2209467) (which allows you to pass "library specific options"). [Comment #9 in it](https://www.drupal.org/node/2209467#comment-10645524) contains a patch that you'll need for it (using Google Charts as the rendering engine).

After you applied that patch, you'll be able to pass any of the specific options to the Google Charts charting engine that correspond to the chart you're trying to create.

If applying the patch is not sufficient, then I'd recommend what's written in the "Bonus tip" of [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929), i.e.:

> You may find it easier to start with a "Table" display and convert it to a chart display after setting up the data. It can be easier to visualize what the result of the chart will be if it's been laid out in a table first.

In other words: before trying to create a chart, make sure the tabular version of it has the correct data displayed.

## Solution 2 - Use Charts to create a Gauge chart

Your sample image in your question rather looks like a ***Gauge*** chart. Have a look at the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) issue about [Support for gauge charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/2269817). After you apply the patch included in [comment # 4](https://www.drupal.org/node/2269817#comment-10290807) of this issue, you'll be able to use the Charts API to create such Gauge charts (using Google Charts as your charting engine). BTW, you can also use [this specific SimplyTest.Me](http://simplytest.me/project/charts/7.x-2.x?patch%5B%5D=https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/charts-add_gauge_support-2269817-0-7.x-2.0-rc1.patch)  link (which has this patch enabled).

Here is a sample of 2 such charts I created in my own environment (using that patch):

---

[image]

---

The first (left) chart is to show a rating like 5.7, and the second (right) chart is to show a rating like 7.2 (both ratings on a scale of 10). Attention: I haven't found any specific option (yet) to show that value of 5.7 (and 7.2) in the Gauge chart, instead of the rounded value 6 (and 7) near the bottom. Though the (red) pointer within the chart seems to correctly reflect the actual values already.

My PHP code for rendering the above 2 Gauge charts looks like so (the various options I used should be self explaining):

```
<?php

 $chart = array(
    '#type' => 'chart',
    '#chart_type' => 'gauge',
    '#chart_library' => 'google',
    '#title' => t('Gauge Chart'),
    '#min' => 0,
    '#max' => 10,
    '#width' => 300,
    '#height' => 300,
    '#greencolor' => '#00AA10',
    '#greenfrom' => 0,
    '#greento' => 5,
    '#redfrom' => 8,
    '#redto' => 10,
    '#redcolor' => '#FF3333',
    '#yellowfrom' => 5,
    '#yellowto' => 8,
    '#yellowcolor' => '#66BB88',
    '#minorticks' => 5,
  );


echo "<p>Left Gauge chart (= Rating 1) : 5.7 / 10 ; Right Gauge chart (Rating 2) : 7.4 / 10 </p>";

  $chart['rating1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'chart_data',
    '#title' => t('Rating 1'),
    '#data' => array(array('Rating1', 5.7)),
  );

  $chart['rating2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'chart_data',
    '#title' => t('Rating 2'),
    '#data' => array(array('Rating2', 7.2)),
  );

  $example['chart'] = $chart;

  return drupal_render($example);
?>
```

If you paste the above code in the body of any content type that allows using the PHP filter, and assuming you have a working internet connection (prereq to use Google Charts), you should get a similar chart in your own environment (provided you also enabled the patch mentioned before).

With the above solution that uses the Charts API, it should be possible to use the same technique for adding an extra column in your tabular Views display, using "rewrite results", in which you also refer to the actual value of the ***Score*** column for each of your views result rows (so that you get 1 Gauge chart somewhere to the right of your Score column).

Disclosure: I'm a **co**-maintainer of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.

Comment: I do not understand why but nothing displays in the block which I create in views. I configured everything well, but i have only the title of my block views... With Google chart tools, the chart appear... I look I look, but I do not find why nothing displays. A problem like that has already indicated? I looked also but nothing found there

Comment: I think there is a problem with the label. I have three field : content title for the "provide labels", rating for the first provides data, and a simple field number for the second provides data. The pie chart appear only when i'm adding a label to the simple field number. The rating field doesn't appear (with label or not)... Hm. I read [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2346991) but the solution won't work for me

Comment: @Hgfdsoiu : please refer to my updated answer: can you edit your question to also show some type of tabular display of the data for which you're trying to create a chart?

Comment: The tabular display correctly the data, but when I tip over it chart, nothing more of displays. I have downloaded a picture of tabular in my question (for example, for node 1, i want to display the score = 3 on 10 (= the reference))

Comment: @Hgfdsoiu : check the "solution 2" I added ... I realized that your chart, IMO, is a Gauge chart (not a pie chart ...).

Comment: For information, I do not succeed in obtaining what I want, but I continue to test. Thanks for your help